# Set method for new button java

Tags: java, android, methods, parameter-passing

I'm beginner to java world. 
I have two questions. 
I'm tring to add a button using java and I could do that

```
Button btn=new Button(this); 
btn.setText("click me");
```

But I had defined a method before called loadthis()

```
Public void loadthis() {
webView.loadUrl(xxx); 
}
```

**first question:** 
How can I link me method to the new button?
is there any way like (.setMethod) to do this without writing the codes of method again?

**second question:**
How can I pass a variable like a string into the method? 
Like passing parameters in javascript.

**thank you so much**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres an answer to your first question,

> How can I link me method to the new button? is there any way like (.setMethod) to do this without writing the codes of method again?

You can use `.addActionListener()` to run code when your button is pressed. You can also use `.addActionListener()` in some other Java window components for other purposes.

*in your constructor*

```java
public Constructor() {
    Button b = new Button("b");
    // Links your method to the button.
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            // Called when button is pressed.
            System.out.println("Button pressed.");
        }
    });
}
```

or

```java
public Constructor() {
    Button b = new Button("b"); // same as above
    b.addActionListener(this::function); // Use method reference instead.
    // other initialization...
}

// The argument in this function is required!
private void function(ActionEvent e) {
    // Called when button is pressed.
}
```

And an answer to your other question,

> How can I pass a variable like a string into the method? Like passing parameters in javascript.

It depends on what you're trying to pass to the function. If its data from another component, it's better to get the data inside the function and put it into a variable. At least in the class you're using, Java dosen't let you pass your own arguments to the function, like the one used here (`ActionListener`).